# Android disallow intercept touch event not working for simple Toast Button app

Tags: android, kotlin

Consider a simple application with just a button in the activity_main layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the main activity I request the button to display a Toast on click. I want it to work even in the multi touch case. Meaning that even if the user click and hold the screen with one finger and further click on the button with another finger, I want the Toast to be displayed.

To do that I used `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` on the parent of the button, see the code below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "This is it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        button.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    }
```

The parent of the button should be the ConstraintLayout which is a ViewGroup in itself.
However it does not work, if I click and hold my finger somewhere on the screen, and I further click on the button, nothing is displayed.
It means that the first touch event is intercepted somewhere and clicking on the button does not trigger the Toast to be displayed.

My approach is surely wrong.

How would you do that ?